# Can't get Newrelic with gunicorn supervisor django 1.6 to work

Tags: python, django, newrelic, supervisord

Im trying to get NewRelic python agent to work with my setup with supervisor and gunicorn, but can't get it to work.

Here is my current supervisor setup that works:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory = /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/myproject/
command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application
```

I tried to do this:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory = /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/myproject/

#Working command
#command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application


command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/newrelic-admin run-program /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application
environment=NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/myproject/newrelic.ini

user = <USER>
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stderr_events_enabled = true
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /home/<USER>/logs/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile = /home/<USER>/logs/gunicorn_err.log
```

but then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 688, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 679, in main
    execsitecustomize()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 547, in execsitecustomize
    import sitecustomize
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.10.2.38-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/bootstrap/sitecustomize.py", line 74, in <module>
    newrelic.agent.initialize(config_file, environment)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.10.2.38-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/config.py", line 1456, in initialize
    log_file, log_level)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.10.2.38-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/newrelic/config.py", line 383, in _load_configuration
    'Unable to open configuration file %s.' % config_file)
newrelic.api.exceptions.ConfigurationError: Unable to open configuration file /.
```

The newrelic.ini file is on that path, so what am I doing wrong?

## Edit:

Path to newrelic.ini file is:

```
/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/myproject/newrelic.ini
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment needs quotes to work.

Here is a working setup:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory = /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/
command=/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/newrelic-admin run-program /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/bin/gunicorn <PROJECT>.wsgi:application
environment=NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE="/home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/<DOMAIN>/<PROJECT>/newrelic.ini"

user = <USER>
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stderr_events_enabled = true
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /home/<USER>/logs/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile = /home/<USER>/logs/gunicorn_err.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using newrelic-admin as is the preferred method when using gunicorn. Use:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory = /home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/my_project/
command=/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/bin/newrelic-admin run-program /home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application
environment=NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=/home/user/.virtualenvs/domain.com/bin/newrelic.ini
```

There is no need to change anything in your wsgi.py file.

Why you have the newrelic.ini file in the bin directory I do not know. You would normally stick it with your project, but then your projects is also under the virtualenv, which is also a bit odd.

For passing environment variables from supervisord see:

- http://supervisord.org/configuration.html
- http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment

For details on the newrelic-admin command and how to use it with gunicorn see:

- https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-admin-script#run-program
- https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-and-gunicorn

Comment: Tried your suggestion, (and moved newrelic.ini to my project path) but get the same error. Updated question with traceback.

Comment: Did you use the supervisord configuration I gave? Edit your question and add the current supervisord configuration you are using. Also give the full path to where newrelic.ini is now located in your question so can compare that with what you are specifying in the supervisord configuration. Also confirm that you have not modified the wsgi.py to add anything related to New Relic as that isn't required if using newrelic-admin and can cause conflicts if both are done.

Comment: Yes. I did use your configuration. 

I have updated my question with full supervisor script.

Comment: What version of supervisord are you using? You need to have a recent version of supervisord 3.0 with environment setting support.

Comment: supervisor/precise uptodate 3.0a8-1.1 installed using `sudo apt-get install supervisor`.

I tried to generate a new newrelic.ini, and now I don't get any errors on my gunicorn log, but when I try to update the gunicorn supervisor script using `sudo supervisorctl update gunicorn` I get this error: `error: <class 'xmlrpclib.Fault'>, <Fault 92: 'CANT_REREAD: Unexpected end of key/value pairs'>: file: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/supervisor/supervisorctl.py line: 933`

Comment: That doesn't look like a New Relic issue but now an issue with supervisord.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'was facing same kind of issue. I was getting following:

```
warpdrive: ERROR (no such file)
```

To my bad I was not updating the supervisorctl after any change to supervisord.conf file. So guys whenever you change the supervisord.conf file then re-run following cmd :

```
sudo supervisorctl update
```

then run :

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

Cheers!